# WCF web service call - which exception(s) to catch?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a program that calls an external web service, and I want to present the user with a friendly dialog if e.g. the server is down, someone cut the cable etc. Assuming the following code

```
try {
   client.MyWebService()
}
catch(? ex)
{
   // display friendly dialog explaining what went wrong
}
```

what exception(s) should I put in place of the question mark in the code? It is kind of hard to actually test situations like this when everything is working smoothly and I have no control over the external part, so some insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to try some specific scenarios, then... just try them and see what happens? In part, the answer depends on how critical it is not to leak any details other than know ones - i.e. is it OK to show "Oops something went wrong" + ex.Message

Comment: While it could be OK from a security standpoint with an "Oops..." message, I would prefer something a little more specific.

Comment: "The lady two doors down is having some housework done, and Jim, the taller of the two workers currently on site, accidentally put a spade through the junction-box; a telecomms engineer has been called, but has 2 other jobs first, plus wants to eat that meatball-sub he has in his van; this will be resolved by 14:12" - not sure there is a specific exception for that... ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to do is take advantage of the .Faulted event on your proxy, which you can wire up like this:

```
((ICommunicationObject)client).Faulted += new EventHandler(client_Faulted);
```

In your `client_Faulted` event handler you can then try re-connecting, or shifting to a backup server, or disabling the UI, logging the error, or displaying a message there.

It's obviously still good practice to wrap each call in a try-catch as well, but the .Faulted event can let you deal with most channel problems even earlier.

As for the exception itself, you can have your service throw a `FaultException` that gets passed back to the client with the details you provide. See an example of its use at [this blog posting](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/).

You won't get a FaultException if the channel itself fails (FaultException is a way for the server to communicate its own internal faults to the client).

For channel faults, you may get a `CommunicationException` or `TimeoutException`.

Finally, take a look at [this project](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex for generating Exception Handling WCF proxies. It may give you a more flexible way of handing faults.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really the client's job to provide as much detail as possible. The maximum amount you really have to provide at the client side is as much as you get back in your exception.

```
var userName = "bob";
try 
{      
   client.MyWebService(userName);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Maybe we know WellKnownExceptions and can provide Foo advice:
   if (ex is WellKnownException)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("WellKnownException encountered, do Foo to fix Bar.");
   }
   //otherwise, this is the best you can do:
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
         "MyWebService call failed for {0}. Details: {1}", userName, ex));
}
```

Comment: If you know it could throw a WellKnownException, then you should make that a separate `catch(WellKnownException wkex)` block.

Comment: @CLaw: It's a matter of style. You can do more concise if/then/else logic in this style depending on the exception type than if each had their own catch block. My example doesn't really demonstrate this, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was asking the same question, as I have to implement some exception handling on web services calls at my client application, so I ended up here. Although it's an old question, I'd like to give my two cents, updating it a little bit.

The answer given by **C. Lawrence Wenham** was already very good and points to some interesting information, although the blog link is broken and Codeplex is now archived.

I found those articles very valuables:

> Sending and Receiving Faults
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/sending-and-receiving-faults
>
> Expected Exceptions
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions

And this article from **Michèle Leroux Bustamante** (apparently the creator of the **Exception Handling WCF Proxy Generator** CodePlex project) is very insighful also:

> An Elegant Exception-Handling Proxy Solution
>   http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/elegant-exception-handling-proxy-solution

I'm still studying the subject but I guess I'll use a lot of ideias from Michèle. I'm just a little bit concerned about using reflection to call the web service's methods, but I wonder if this would have any impact in such kind of operation, that is inherently slow already.

Just to answer here explicitly what was asked originally, which are the exceptions that could be tested against a web service call:

```
string errorMessage = null;

// A class derived from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.
MyWebService wcfClient = new MyWebService();
try
{
   wcfClient.Open();
   wcfClient.MyWebServiceMethod();
}
catch (TimeoutException timeEx)
{
   // The service operation timed out.
   errorMessage = timeEx.Message;
}
catch (FaultException<ExceptionDetail> declaredFaultEx)
{
   // An error on the service, transmitted via declared SOAP
   // fault (specified in the contract for an operation).
   errorMessage = declaredFaultEx.Detail.Message;
}
catch (FaultException unknownFaultEx)
{
   // An error on the service, transmitted via undeclared SOAP
   // fault (not specified in the contract for an operation).
   errorMessage = unknownFaultEx.Message;
}
catch (CommunicationException commEx)
{
   // A communication error in either the service or client application.
   errorMessage = commEx.Message;
}
finally
{
   if (wcfClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
      wcfClient.Abort();
   else
      wcfClient.Close();
}
```

As stated by the articles, the order the exceptions are catched is important, since `FaultException<TDetail>` derives from `FaultException`, and `FaultException` derives from `CommunicationException`.