# What possible WCF exceptions can be thrown from a method call on a service proxy?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am using WCF and need to catch all the exceptions that can occur when calling a method on the service proxy, so that I can then instead return a status value. I want to do this to encapsulate/hide the underlying WCF implemenation. An example code would be this:

```
public Status StartProcess(string outputFolder)
{
        return service.StartProcess(outputFolder);
}
```

`service.StartProcess` returns a `Status`-enum and I would like to catch all possible WCF exceptions that can occur from the call to `service.StartProcess(outputFolder);` so that I can return a corresponding `Status`-enum. From testing I arrived at this:

```
public Status StartProcess(string outputFolder)
{
    try
    {
        return service.StartProcess(outputFolder);
    }
    catch (System.ObjectDisposedException) // occurs, when client closed the connection previously
    {
        return Status.ClientDisconnected;
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException) // occurs, when server unexpectedly closed the connection previously
    {
        return Status.CommunicationFailed;
    }
}
```

So my question is: Are these all the exception I have to handle in this case or are there other exceptions I should anticipate?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question, there's a lot of exceptions that can be thrown, I could mention `EndpointNotFoundException`, `TimeoutException`, `MessageSecurityException`, `TargetInvocationException`, `CommunicationException` and `InvalidOperationException`, but could be others.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9370880/569662

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best workaround for the WCF client \`using\` block issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue). On the surface it's not about the same thing, but many of the answers document many exceptions.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374421/wcf-web-service-call-which-exceptions-to-catch?rq=1